# Service Fabric application's root directory

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In my code I fail at

```
if (!File.Exists(_configurationFileName)) {...}
```

In the immediate window I made a call to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and it pointed me to the "**work**" folder rather than the "**code**" folder which I would have expected.

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
"C:\\SfDevCluster\\Data\\_App\\_Node_0\\My.Application.Type_App2\\work"
```

So my configuration file which is sitting right next to the executable is of course not being found.

Now I wonder what the solution is.
Since I also want to  keep running the console application I don't want to implement any "if service fabric hosting, then change current directory, ..." workaround.

Any recommendations? What about my .exe.config files (if I had any, how would they be found)?

What's the reason for Service Fabric settings the current directory to "work"? Is this some kind of security mechanism?

Comment: Same issue here with web site and views..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how i just did it change the service manifest to point at the code

```
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>configui.exe</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

Comment: "CodeBase" rather than "CodePackage" but yes - somehow the project assistant didn't add this information to my service definition.

Comment: In my case i copied a web into a non web project .. I found it by a new site from template that worked and doing a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could do some simple reflection and get the folder the executing assembly is in, then reference that file in that location. I did this successfully for an ancillary file I needed that is deployed to the same folder as my executable.

```
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath), "myfilename.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select build action as 'content' and select 'copy if newer' in the properties so that it gets copied to the output folder.

Comment: This is not my problem. The config files are where I expect them to be. My "current directory" is not.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Application Debug Mode" to "Keep Application" resolved a similar issue I was having where my files were not getting copied to the final deploy area on my local service fabric.

It had been set to "Refresh Application" which is in preview as I type this. But that mode wasn't copying my wwwroot folder over, so my view engine (Nancy in this case) was not finding my views.

Right click your service fabric project > properties > Application > Application Debug Mode > Keep Application